# Changing from standard sqlite to postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to change from the standard sqlite database to postgresql in my Django project. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Installed postgresql
2. Created a database and a user with privileges for writing to it
3. Changing the database setting in settings.py:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
           'NAME': 'workout',
           'USER': 'admin',
           'PASSWORD': 'admin',
           'HOST': 'localhost',
           'PORT': '5432',
       }
   }
   ```

Then, when I try to migrate, this happens (warning for long error trace):

```
(workout) Sahands-MBP:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, workoutcal
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying workoutcal.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying workoutcal.0002_auto_20171215_1102... OK
  Applying workoutcal.0003_auto_20171215_1153...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "workoutcal_user"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 87, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 429, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "workoutcal_user"

(workout) Sahands-MBP:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, workoutcal
Running migrations:
  Applying workoutcal.0003_auto_20171215_1153...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "workoutcal_user"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 87, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 429, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "workoutcal_user"

(workout) Sahands-MBP:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, workoutcal
Running migrations:
  Applying workoutcal.0003_auto_20171215_1153...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "workoutcal_user"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 87, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 429, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "workoutcal_user"
```

So there's seems to be some kind of error with workoutcal_user. I'm not sure how django names the tables, but the only model I have defined in `workoutcal/models.py` is this one:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Must be a valid email address.'),
        error_messages={
            'unique':_("A user with that email address already exists."),
        },
    )
```

I'm guessing this is the model that's causing problems. My question is obviously, why? What does it mean that multiple default values have been specified for the `id` field of this model? And how can I make them only one?

EDIT:

As Daniel Roseman requested, the failing migration 0003_auto_20171215_1153.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.5 on 2017-12-15 11:53
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('workoutcal', '0002_auto_20171215_1102'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, default=1, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='email',
            field=models.EmailField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that email address already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters of fewer. Must be a valid email address.', max_length=150, unique=True, verbose_name='email address'),
        ),
    ]
```

EDIT 2:

I followed cezar's instructions. Upon reaching the last step and trying to migrate, this error occured.

```
(workout) Sahands-MBP:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py migrate workoutcal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 86, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 298, in check_consistent_history
    connection.alias,
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency workoutcal.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

What is this other migration? How can I completely erase migrations history?

EDIT 3: After dropping every single table in the database with `DROP TABLE 'tablename' CASCADE;`, removing all files in workoutcal/migrations and running `makemigrations` and `migrate` again, it worked.

Comment: Changed it. The same problem remains.

Comment: Show your model `workoutcal_user`

Comment: It's in the question already. I can't think of any other model that it could be, that's the only one I've defined.

Comment: How can I remove default values specified for it?

Comment: You should show the code of the failing migration, workoutcal.0003_auto_20171215_1153.

Comment: I've included it now. See edit.

Comment: Change the column name from `id` to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, default=1, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
```

The `id` field must be unique as it is a primary key. It means it can't have a default value that is repeating in many entries.

I'd suggest a quick and dirty solution. Go directly to your PosgreSQL command line. Delete all entries in the table `django_migrations` for the app `workoutcal`:

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app = 'workoutcal';
```

Delete the contents of the directory `migrations` in your app `workoutcal`:

```
rm -rf workoutcal/migrations/*
```

Then generate new migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations workoutcal
```

This should create new initial migration. After that the command:

```
python manage.py migrate workoutcal
```

should populate the database without any problems.

EDIT:

The migration `admin.0001_initial` depends on `workoutcal.0001_initial`. I can't explain this dependency. You can use django command line tools to revert the migrations for `admin`:

```
python manage.py migrate admin zero
```

With the option `zero` you tell django to revert all migrations and establish the state before the initial migration has been run. Instead of `zero` you can specify the number of the migration. In your particular situation you'll need however to revert to the initial state using `zero`.

After that run the migrations for `workoutcal` and after that for `admin`:

```
python manage.py migrate workoutcal
python manage.py migrate admin
```

Comment: Thank you @cezar. Unfortunately there was an error when I tried your solution. Could you please look at EDIT 2?